# Delphi SVN cleanup

Tags: delphi, svn

I am trying to provide a lot of context below for this problem so that experienced people can read the symptoms. I expect more questions will need answering to get to the bottom of it.

The short form of this question is how do I remove the source control history from a project in Delphi? (The local project folder) After removing the .svn and .local directories Delphi still wont svn import. There is nothing in the repository. This seems to be a problem with the Delphi integration. Some local caching of activity that does not seem to be relying on the repository for information.

Longer form: I recently setup the Delphi XE3 included subversion client and server. It is running as a service on Windows. The setup was done with sc as per the svn-book.
I successfully figured it all out by trial and error. With a fair bit of error over the last few days.
In trying to clean up my source code and repositories to get to a clean install I found that I needed to remove repositories from the server and re-create them. I also thought if I removed the .svn directories from the source that it would remove all traces of source control. This did not work. So I tried to additionally remove the .local files, which do have some version history in them.

When I load the project group and switch to the import tab, I still see recent comments showing my initial commit.

In addition when I try to Import a dialog comes up saying one of my big key .pas files is already under version control. Another file, a dproj file it says is not under version control. When I check the repo with

```
svn ls
```

some folders got made, but there are no files in the repository.

The config file is setup such that I should need to supply a password. It never asks for one. I just left the default security in place because I dont need to concern myself with it much. Just enough to stop mistakes. It is on a local network. SVN Import didnt require it either.

I can manually add files with svn import. I am using the svn: protocol prefix with svnserve.exe running as a service. Authentication is default. It works without passwords for some reason. It shouldnt do that.

```
svnserve.conf has the following: (comments omitted for bevity)
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = D:\SVNRepos\conf\passwd
realm = Root
force-username-case = none

svn --Version says:
svn, version 1.7.5 (r1336830)
   compiled May 11 2012, 02:21:17
```

Comment: @WarrenP you are completely wrong on this point.

Comment: @Michael without some screenshots and step-by-step description of your actions its very hard to tell what's going on. My guess now is that you simply didn't `svn commit` your changes in the working copy. Just begin from the scratch after removing /.svn directory (if there is still any).

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Use *File->Open from Version Control*. Specify the repository and project you want to check out, and a target folder. Let the IDE check out into a new working directory, and work on your project there. Once you've done that, use the Project Manager to work with the repository files (right-click on the individual file and use the version control items from the context menu).

Comment: @KenWhite as far as I understood, Michael haven't yet added the project to SVN.

Comment: @bahrep: *After removing the .svn and .local directories* implies that it was there at one point, or those directories wouldn't have been there to remove. :-) If it hasn't been added, then it is indeed easier to do via the command line (and even easier via TortoiseSVN) first.

Comment: Don't use Delphi as your subversion client. Use the command line tools, or better, Tortoise. The convenience of the svn IDE integration is entirely offset by the lameness of the IDE's svn client implementation.

Answer (score 0):

*At first, SVN is not CVS. While CVS is legacy system with many problems, SVN is a modern centralized version-control system (git fans may disagree, but this is another topic).*

Subversion 1.7 is out of date and no longer supported. The current release is Subversion 1.9 and it has many improvements compared with 1.7. SVN 1.8 is still supported as well. Therefore, you should definitely upgrade your client and server to the latest version.

Returning to your problem: you haven't specified any errors that you get in Delphi XE3 IDE. Do you get any?

When you `svn add` files in Subversion working copy, you schedule them to be committed next time you run `svn commit`. So there is a chance that you haven't actually committed them to the repository.

If your code was already imported to Subversion repository, then it has to be there. Double-check this with `svn ls -r <URL>` again. Then you could checkout a working copy using `svn checkout <URL>`.

BTW, `.local` files do not relate to Subversion. These seem to be some project files of the IDE, but I'm not sure.

And if you have issues with Subversion server setup on Windows, there are packages that should help you. See the [binary packages page](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows).

Comment: I used the distro that comes with Delphi XE3. It uses the Colabnet DLLs so I figured that was what I should use. Delphi uses Import for new files, and it picks the ones to save. Delphi XE3 does not support other version control. But newer releases do. I am mainly looking for help from someone who knows the kinks and bends of the Delphi XE3 implementation.

Comment: @Michael sorry, I'm not familiar with this IDE.

Comment: Subversion's merging and workflows are limiting, and better tools exist. Use them. Subversion was very modern in 2000, when you were probably using Windows 98 on your PC. It's positively archaic now. I use it every day and its limitations are infuriating. For a single-user, having to administer SVN servers, and dealing with FSFS corruption is a huge time suck. Just DON'T.

Comment: @Warren Subversion is fine as a centralised vcs. The real problem here is trying to use Delphi as your main subversion client.

Comment: A centralized VCS is a silly thing when the server runs on your own computer, and is for your own use, moreso when it's Subversion with its completely lame implementation of FSFS, it's server-side file system corruption problems, and its client-side working copy corruption issues (even in svn 1.9, using sqlite inside the .svn and its problems with the pristine-copy folders). That being said, if you ARE going to use it, you should be using TortoiseSVN GUI, and the SVN commandline and should learn to use them, and should deploy a real SVN server, perhaps one from collabnet.